# Someone is locking /etc/group for a very long time - what to do?

Tags: group, suse, etc

I want to change something in `/etc/group` - namely, to add some user to some group. But something - I don't know what or who - has created an `/etc/group.lock` file. `fuser /etc/group.lock` gives nothing, but that doesn't tell me much.

How can I tell who's the "culprit"? And whether I can safely delete the lock file and be able to change `/etc/group` again?

Note: I'm using SLES 15 on an x86_64 machine.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
lslocks
```

will show files locked with flock manually or by apps.

Try using lsof to get the user who locked the file.

```
lsof /etc/.group.swp
```

Should show similar too.

```
~]# lsof /etc/.group.swp
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
vim     27611 root    4u   REG  253,1    12288 6299017 /etc/.group.swp
```

or possibly

```
vim /etc/group
```

vim will show (if the file is locked) that it is locked, by who, if the file has been modified etc.

Output of vim on locked file

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/.group.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Mon Feb 24 14:49:08 2020
         file name: /etc/group
          modified: no
         user name: root   host name: testfoonameserver101
        process ID: 27611 (still running)
While opening file "/etc/group"
             dated: Fri Feb 21 09:23:49 2020
```

Comment: Will there be a `group.lock` when somebody edits `/etc/group` with `vi`? I mean, such a lock file is not used in addition to the `.swp` file elsewhere.

Comment: Can it ever be anybody _other than root_?

Comment: no I reread your question. The file is locked with vi edits but not with a .lock file 
use lslocks for listing locks with flock. 
I also added this to my answer above.

Comment: First of all - +1 for `lslocks`. Now, if lslocks doesn't show locks for /etc/group nor for any related file (eg nothing for `.group.swp`) - does that mean it's safe?

Answer (score 2):

You could be in Luck! There was a bug sometime back about .lock files not unlocking after issuing a useradd, though I recall it being REHL 9 or something of the sort.

If you read the files they may contain a PID corresponding to the last known actor on the file. Additionally you may be able to add a user and it will complete successfully despite printing the opposite in STDout. You're running a 2017/2018 OS so I can only hope that it does not contain a bug similar to what I described.

Resource: https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2004:472